# Move to the beginning of the file in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How do I move to the beginning of the file in emacs (i.e. the effect of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> in windowed text editors)?

Mashing pageup does not move the cursor to the beginning (nor does `Ctrl+Home`, ofc).

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-Point.html) the shortcut for the desired result  is described as:

> `M-<` :
>   Move to the top of the buffer (beginning-of-buffer). With numeric argument n, move to n/10 of the way from the top.
>
> `M->` : 
>   Move to the end of the buffer (end-of-buffer).

However `Meta + <` yields "No M-x tags-search or M-x tags-query-replace in progress" message.

I am typing the shortcut as `Alt + Shift + ,`  since to get the "`<`" I have to type "`Shift + ,`"

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
Turns out this is an issue only when running emacs through screen, where the keyboard shortcuts are, for some reason, misinterpreted.
For example, `C-Home` gives this error message:

`M-[ 1 ; 5 h (translated from M-[ 1 ; 5 H) is undefined`

Any way around it?

Comment: I mention the relevant shortcut in the quotation, which is the standard one as I can see (e.g. same one in [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf) emacs cheatsheet). It does not work for me though, as I explain in my post.

Comment: Check that key sequence is bound to `beginning-of-buffer` with `C-h k` followed by `M-<`. You are entering it correctly

Comment: Are you using Emacs inside a terminal, or are you using the GUI version of Emacs.  In case it makes a difference, you might as well mention also the operating system and version of Emacs that you are presently using.  `M-x emacs-version`

Comment: Ok, I possibly feel like an idiot, because following @jenesaisquoi 's instructions I see that indeed it's mapped to the standard shortcuts, but `Ctrl+Home` does work now - no idea why it did not before. 

I do not know how to type `M-<` : `Alt+Shift+,` successfully. It results in `M-,` when I try.

I am only using emacs in a terminal.

Comment: In that case, please consider deleting your question, as it is unlikely to help someone else. Thx.

Comment: I am undeleting and updating the question.

Answer (score 26):

This works on newer Emacs

```
Esc followed by < #beginning of file
Esc followed by > #end of file
```

Works great in combination with ssh and Tmux

Answer (score 4):

I cannot reproduce the exact behavior as <kbd>C-HOME</kbd> that you experience.  For me it translates to `M-[ 1 ;`, without the `5H` (but that is actually inserted...).

But, given that, here's how I would set up the binding.

I'd go into the `*scratch*` buffer and type

`(read-key-sequence "please type C-home ")` <kbd>C-j</kbd>

Which will prompt you for a key sequence, so do <kbd>C-HOME</kbd> and Emacs should insert the following right after the `read-key-sequence` line:

```
    "^[[1;"
    5H
```

This shows me the actual string for the key sequence, as well as the mysterious `5H`.

Using the string, I'd set up the binding in my .emacs like so:

```
(global-set-key "^[[1;" 'beginning-of-buffer)
```

This will define the key binding appropriately, except that (for me) it now inserts `5H` at the top of the buffer.  I believe the `5H` is a product of screen somehow...

---

*Updated to add:*

The `5H` annoys me, but as far as I can tell, Emacs thinks we are literally typing it.  So, I coded up two alternatives which result in the same behavior.

The first uses `keyboard-quit` to interrupt the key sequence *after* getting to the beginning of the buffer.  This prevents the `5H` from being inserted.  But it has the downside of doing a `keyboard-quit` - which will flash/ding at you ever time.  Kind of annoying.

```
(global-set-key "^[[1;" 'my-bob)

(defun my-bob ()
  "Go to beginning of buffer, then quit"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (keyboard-quit))
```

To avoid the `keyboard-quit`, I wrote a different version which runs a little snippet of code which deletes the `5H` if it exists.  It's a little more involved, but does the job.

```
(global-set-key "^[[1;" 'my-bob)

(defun my-bob ()
  "Go to beginning of buffer, then delete any 5H inserted by the binding"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil 'delete-inserted-chars "5H"))

(defun delete-inserted-chars (chars)
  (save-excursion
    (backward-char (length chars))
    (if (looking-at (regexp-quote chars))
        (delete-char (length chars)))))
```

The `delete-inserted-chars` can be reused for other bindings in screen which happen to insert characters as well.

Comment: just use (global-set-key (kbd "\033[1;5H") 'beginning-of-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do it go to line one:

```
C-u 1 M-g M-g
```